# How can I run the code below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I wrote these codes to manage my mssql database online but it doesn't work. What is my fault? I tried but I couldn't find my fault. Can you help me please? and any help would be appreciated...

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<%page = Request.Querystring("page")%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sql Statement</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="?page=run">
            <input type="text" name="code" size="100">
            <input type="submit" name="run" value="run">
        </form>
        <% if page = "error" then %>
            <p><b>Error!</b></p>
        <% end if %>
        <% if page = "thanks" then %>
            <p>Ok!</p>
        <% end if %>

        <% 
        if page="run" then
            code = Request.form("code")
            On Error Resume Next 

            StrDB = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _ 
            Server.MapPath("database/data.mdb" ) 

            Set StrConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection" ) 
            StrConn.Open StrDB 

            Set recordset = StrConn.Execute(code)

            If Err <> 0 Then 
                Response.redirect "?page=error" 
            Else 
                Response.redirect "?page=thanks" 
            End If 

            StrConn.Close 
            Set StrConn = Nothing 
        End IF
        %>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide us the error message at least.....

Comment: Try turning `Option Explicit` on to start, and also include the language tags  (`<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>` as a bare minimum, though a code page would also be a good idea) - format your page properly.

Comment: Are you supplying the value for the `code` textbox? If so, what is it?

Comment: Thanks for replies. I want to write a statement like "Drop from xxxx" into the textbox and then when I click on the run button, the statement must run. As I said before current strings say "ERROR!" because of the the codes I wrote...

Comment: What are you putting in the `code` textbox? If it's not valid, executable SQL, then naturally your error handling will return the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the code below at the **top of the page**:

```
page = Request.Querystring("page")
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio for your reply. But it always says "Error!" when I click on the run button. The Code doesn't work.